nanoTime drift vs currentTimeMillis
Time measurements relative of a starting point taken with nanoTime vs currentTimeMillis diverge after at most three minutes.
This concerns Windows implementations of JDK11++, possibly earlier. Linux doesn’t seem to be affected.
Since the most likely culprit is Windows and I believe currentTimeMillis to be the stable time function while nanoTime is off, I’d like to know how Java obtains those timestamps.
Under Linux, we see differences stemming from the way how we scale up the millis to nanos. The differences are well-behaved and within millisecond accuracy.
Since both values are computed against their respective starting point, taken within a few µs of each other, one would think that they stay within millisecond accuracy like it happens under Linux. Any irregularities regarding the timer cadence shouldn’t matter as the timer only serves to give a slow, readable progression of measurements where the exact timing doesn’t matter.
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ClockWatch {

    static final long StartNS = System.nanoTime();
    static final long StartMS = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance( Locale.US);
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits( 3);
        nf.setGroupingUsed( true);

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "HH:mm:ss");
        df.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "GMT"));
        ScheduledExecutorService ses = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor( 1);

        Runnable compareJob = () -> {
            long nowNS = System.nanoTime() - StartNS;
            long nowMS = System.currentTimeMillis() - StartMS;
            long tookNS = ( System.nanoTime() - StartNS) - nowNS;
            long diffNS = 1_000_000 * nowMS - nowNS;
            double driftPercent = 100.0 * diffNS / nowNS;
            System.out.println( df.format( new Date( nowMS))
                + " currentTimeMillis is "
                + ( diffNS < 0 ? "" : " ")
                + nf.format( 1e-6 * diffNS)
                + " ms faster than nanoTime, took "
                + nf.format( tookNS) + " ns, drift "
                + nf.format( driftPercent) + " % since start"
            );
        };
        ses.scheduleAtFixedRate( compareJob, 1, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}

The reason why this bothers me is that I want to reuse an existing nano timestamp and convert it into an equivalent to currentTimeMillis without calling the latter. I know, it only takes 4 ns under Windows on recent hardware.

Perhaps I should provide some more background after reading the comments. All machines I used had been up for days and have pretty accurate clocks, thanks to chrony and ntp, in the sub-millisecond range. So I wouldn’t expect any sudden jumps.
I am aware of the quirks of nanoTime and currentTimeMillis. I shall perhaps get rid of both in favor of Instant.now, so thanks for reminding me.
My main reason was that I wanted to log events using log4j2 (configured with a full timestamp). There are many threads logging into the same file, asynchonously. This is one of the bigger machines. Under certain circumstances, the logging threads would clog up since log4j can’t keep up, thereby slowing down the logging threads. In order to alleviate this, I moved the calls to log4j into a queue serviced by another thread. Since I now expected this thread to incur queue latencies, I wanted to add another timestamp to those log messages, reflecting the time when they were added to the log queue. For this inner timestamp, I have an existing nano-Timestamp, that I wanted to reuse in a way that matches the log4j-timestamp as part of the log message pattern.
I have since gotten around this problem by obtaining another currentTimeMillis timestamp, but this involved adding another long field to many objects and one more measurement, both I’d like to avoid. Since I need my measurements to be compatible with whatever log4j uses, it looks like I need to experiment with Instant.now now.

The source code for System.nanoTime in the OpenJDK project says this method is implemented natively. I cannot find the native implementation on GitHub. That implementation might address your issue.

As far as I can tell, nanoTime calls os::javaTimeNanos and currentTimeMillis calls os::javaTimeMillis (both links for os_windows.cpp from OpenJDK). And then they call QueryPerformanceCounter and GetSystemTimeAsFileTime from Win32, respectively.

@Slaw Thank you for your efforts. Are you saying the differences varied, either more or less? So not really an accumulating drift? (I am curious, though this issue really is moot as the two measurements serve entirely different purposes per Answer by Wasserman.)

@Basil Correct, I'm not seeing any accumulated drift on my Windows machine. The nanoTime duration was, on average, ~0.6ms shorter than the currentTimeMillis duration (measured every 3 seconds for 15 minutes). But you're right that it doesn't really matter; what I'm seeing is not guaranteed and they serve different purposes anyway.

Hello H, actually your question is tricky, because it is impossible to compare both measures, since StartMS, influences nomNs - StartNS (it is contained), and nowNS influences nowMS - startMs (it is also contained), so any attempt to compare, is fruitless.

What is the output exactly? How does time diverge? (I don't see this in my run) Also, what JDK and Windows versions/builds do you use?

Sorry for coming back to this only now. Like I said, it occured for me on any Windows machine I tried be it a recent server or workstation edition. The JDK version (post 11) didn’t matter, either. Since I originally wanted to file a JVM bug, I also tried the latest ea build of JDK-24. Same everywhere.
After writing this question, I noticed a similar one regarding macOS, which apparently uses two different time sources, too. Linux seems to use the same for nanos and millis, it seems, The calls also take the same time.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64961281/869736 is not precisely an answer to this question, but includes key relevant facts.  Most notably, most computers' hardware clocks are set up to periodically receive corrections from a time server.  currentTimeMillis will observe these corrections as jumps or paused; nanoTime will not observe them at all.  currentTimeMillis accesses the OS's time through whatever facilities the OS provides.
You have correctly observed that cTM and nanoTime will diverge over time, and not even an enormous amount of time.  That's an unavoidable fact; I would not expect it to be perfect indefinitely regardless of your OS.
In general, the cure ought to be to treat these as wholly different measurements that rarely happen to coincide. Always use:

System.nanoTime for elapsed time in nanoseconds
Instant.now for the current time on the clock, captured in microseconds in Java 9+ (milliseconds in Java 8), with nanoseconds resolution.
System.currentTimeMillis as the legacy method for current time on the clock, limited to milliseconds resolution.




Method
Status
Purpose
Resolution




System.nanoTime
modern
Elapsed time
nanoseconds


Instant.now
modern
Current moment on the clock
nanoseconds   Current moment captured in microseconds in Java 9+, milliseconds in Java 8


System.currentTimeMillis
legacy
Current moment on the clock
milliseconds




To complete the answer: @RalfH - you explain the underlying intent behind yoru question which is 'I want to reuse the result of nanoTime as a way to obtain a cTM based timestamp without paying the performance penalty of actually calling cTM'. Well, you simply cannot do that, and there is no way to fix that. You must pay that penalty, or find a way to no longer need cTM for whatever you need cTM for. For the reasons Louis explains here. There is no way to cTMize the result of nanoTime, on any OS. You observed it was millisec accurate on linux.. that is not guaranteed either.

accepted for mentioning Instant.now :)
